# Break out of switch statement

Tags: objective-c, c, scope, switch-statement, break

Do I always have to `break` out of a switch statement; is it unsafe to simply have a semicolon `;` to exit?

```
switch ( (rand() % 2) ) {
    case 0:
    // Do foo;
    break;
    case 1:
    // Do nothing
    ;
    default:
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) (a function that copies N bytes from one spot in memory to another):

```
send(to, from, count)
register short *to, *from;
register count;
{
        register n = (count + 7) / 8;
        switch(count % 8) {
        case 0: do {    *to = *from++;
        case 7:         *to = *from++;
        case 6:         *to = *from++;
        case 5:         *to = *from++;
        case 4:         *to = *from++;
        case 3:         *to = *from++;
        case 2:         *to = *from++;
        case 1:         *to = *from++;
                } while(--n > 0);
        }
}
```

It only works -- and, yes, it really works -- because all of the cases fall through to the next because none of the cases use `break;`.   So, yes, you *must* use `break;` to exit the `case`, but falling through to the next `case` can be potentially useful.

Though, as Duff's Device succinctly demonstrates, falling through by *not* using `break;` has a distinct code smell of being *too tricky for your own good*.

Comment: Absolutely.  I was wondering where you draw the lines between goals like "Optimally refactored", "Efficiency", and "Readability".  It does smell - that's why I posted it! :D

Comment: Also, for Duff's example, in Obj-C do they prefer pointer arithmetic over OOP?

Comment: @user2000809 In ObjC, you'd generally isolate any tricksy C or C++ code behind either a pure C API or encapsulated in an ObjC class.  There is certainly use for pointer arithmetic and other, relatively obtuse, C-isms that are very fast, but isolating them behind API makes refactoring, testing, and debugging easier.

Comment: Incidentally, the original Device uses `*to` rather than `*to++` because it was copying to a specific location with special significance (although I don't know/remember what that was). If you wanted to copy into a section of ordinary memory, you'd use `*to++` on every one of those lines.

Answer (score 12):

A semicolon doesn't exit the switch. Otherwise every statement (which is terminated with a semicolon) would exit the switch.

If you don't add the break, the next case will be executed. In your case above it might work as `default` is next and it's empty, but usually your code will do unexpected things...

Comment: This is a more succinct and precise answer than mine, but I've always wanted an excuse to toss Duff's Device onto SO...

Comment: @bbum Nice. Good explanation of how to (and why you shouldn't) use the feature of not adding the `break`.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't 'exit' the switch, as I intended it to fall through and do nothing - so this should not cause any bugs as the `switch` scope ends with the bracket?

Comment: You don't need to add the semicolon, it adds no value. Yes, the switch scope is defined by the brackets.

Comment: @user2000809 It doesn't cause a bug until you go back to add case 2: and forget to put in the break in case 1 ;)

Personally I'd lean towards putting the break in unless you really need fall through behaviour.  And if really need fall through think hard about whether you're being, as bbum says, "too tricky for your own good".

Comment: And add a nice comment to describe what you're doing, so in 3 months time you remember what is was and why...

Answer (score 2):

A `;` will not prevent the control to fall to next statement.

**So  always use `break;` with `switch` and there is no good alternative.**

A `;` is just a statement terminator.

---

As per your code,

```
case 1:
    // Do nothing
    ;
```

This is really not required if your case has nothing to do. You can simply omit this.

Comment: True, I could omit for private use.  I left in in place along with the comments for completeness, so it is clear that the coding is deliberate (and not say, forgotten) in the API

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason why the switch statement only works with constants and it needs breaks.
Switch is implemented with labels not conditionals.

```
switch (x){
   case 1: printf("1"); break;
   case 2: printf("2"); break;
}
```

is the equivalent of

```
goto label_x; // where x is replaced with it's value
label_1:
        printf("1");
        break;
label_2:
        printf("2");
        break;
```

That is why in C/C++ if you do not put a break it will just continue to the next line of code ( fall through ) .

You should check C++ control structures here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

search for "The selective structure: switch"

Comment: Or don't use `goto`? `goto` is *considered harmful*

Comment: I never suggest to use `goto`

Comment: Goto is not harmful, it's just per say. It just ruins the structure of the code.So cause of that it makes mistakes easier since the code is not organized. Also it kinda defeates the point of structured programming.

Comment: Right.  `goto` = sequential != OOP.  I meant 'harmful' as a shout out to Dijkstra :D